# Complexity of active set method for Quadratic Programming

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization, quadratic-programming

The Quadratic Programming problem is as follows:

$$\min_x \{\frac12x^THx+x^Tg\}$$

$$Ax\le b$$
where $H$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

What is the complexity of the active set method for quadratic programming?

The complexity might be dependant on size of $x$ or both size of $x$ and size of constraints.

Comment: This is an exercise in Google and Wikipedia that you don't need us for.

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking for a course in combinatorial optimization, not a Q&A platform.

Comment: We'd prefer that you ask one question, not six.  Also, we want you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and show us in the question where you looked and what you've found.  What research have you done?  Where did you look?  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Great, thank you for narrowing the question.  Now, I imagine that the next thing community members will likely be wondering is: what research have you done?  Where have you looked, and what have you found so far?  See [my prior comment](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54413/complexity-of-quadratic-programming?noredirect=1#comment114436_54413).

Comment: @D.W., I have found Active set method in [page 7](http://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter3.pdf) but its mathematics are so heavy for me to understand it.